# Wordpress page template rewriting

Tags: wordpress, templates, rewriting

I want to rewrite a page template url via .htaccess from `www.xxx.com/pagename?id=1&name=2` to `www.xxx.com/pagename/1/2`.

The original URL works but not the rewrite url.

please help

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide what you've tried achieving the task? Otherwise have you tried the permalink in the settings to "Post name".

[image]